# How to use a variable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

How to use variable in jQuery? I used the var i, Here's the code:

```
var i=0;
for (i=0;i<=5;i++){
   $('.slide:eq(i)').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with jQuery. It's just plain JavaScript and strings.

Comment: Note that you can simply: `for (var i=0; ...` to declare your `i` as function-local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't "work" because it's treated like a plain string.

You need to [concatenate](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+concatenation) with '+'.

```
$('.slide:eq('+i+')').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
```

You can also use:

```
$('.slide').eq(i).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
```

which is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead...

```
for (i=0;i<=5;i++){
   $('.slide').eq(i).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
}
```

The reason is that when you wrap the string in quotes, it's just a string!

If you want to use :eq() instead of .eq(i) you would need to do

```
for (i=0;i<=5;i++){
   $('.slide:eq('+i+')').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
}
```

Comment: You should either include the original `var i=0;` or (better) include the `var` in your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to place the value of `i` into the jQuery selector.

```
var i=0;
for (i=0;i<=5;i++){
   $('.slide:eq(' + i + ')').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why set i to 0 twice? Try something like below;

```
for (var i=0;i<=5;i++){
   $('.slide:eq('+ i + ')').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
}
```

What you are doing now is using the variable i as an string. SO jquery will see i really as as i. Try concatenating it like above.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
var i=0;

for (i=0;i<=5;i++){

   $('.slide:eq(' + i + ')').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);

}
```